# (Wordpress) My custom widget is loading pages instead of blog posts. How do I correct this?

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom widget that loads featured posts based upon posts being assigned a category 'Featured'. The widget worked fine until I updated Wordpress, now the widget seems to be searching for and load pages, rather than posts.

I've tried to fix the issue myself, but after looking at the code for a number of hours. I would appreciate some assistance correcting this. Please see widget code below.

Thanks

'''

```
class Event_Featured_Posts_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    // setup the widget name, description, etc...
    public function __construct() {

      $widget_ops = array(
          'classname' => 'widget-featured-posts',
          'description' => 'Display Featured Posts Widget',
      );
      parent::__construct( 'event_featured_posts', 'Featured Posts', $widget_ops );

    }

    // back-end display of widget
    public function form( $instance ) {
        echo '<p><strong>No options for this Widget!</strong></p>';
    }

    // front-end display of widget
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

      $postfeat = array(

        'post_type' => 'post', //write slug of post type
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category_name' => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
      );

      $featPosts = new WP_Query( $postfeat );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        ?>

        <div class="text-center">

            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="event-widget-title">Featured Posts</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row text-center" id="featured">

                <?php if ( $featPosts->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $featPosts->have_posts() ) :
                    $featPosts->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="featured-posts-box col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <?php if( event_get_attachment() ): ?>
                          <a class="standard-featured-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                              <div class="standard-featured background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo event_get_attachment(); ?>);">
                                  <img class="image-invisible" src="<?php echo event_get_attachment(); ?>">
                              </div>
                          </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="featured-posts-text">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                            <!-- <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p> -->
                            <div class="featured-entry-meta text-center">
                                 <?php echo event_posted_meta(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <p id="featured_excerpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More >></a></p> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

            </div><!--featured-->

        </div>

        <?php

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget( 'Event_Featured_Posts_Widget' );
} );
```

'''

Comment: The query looks right. Did you try to check or dump the value of the $featPosts? Are you using any pre_get_posts hook, or any plugins that may alter the query? First thing to do is to disable all plugins, check if the widget still shows pages. If the widget is not showing any pages after disabling the plugins, then one of the plugins is causing the issue.

Comment: I'm not using any pre_get_get_posts hooks, only thing I can can think of is it may be the Page Builder by SiteOrigin plugin I'm using. I will disable it and check.

Comment: It seems to be the Page Builder by SiteOrigin plugin, once deactivated the posts show.